# Path to toolbox in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arctoolbox, python-toolbox, model

I have got a toolbox full of models to run from one script.

Is there any code that calculates the location of script from which I can get the path to my toolbox?

Script and models are imported if that matters. Toolbox is going to be used on a few computers and running a script is more nice way than searching for models.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what setup do you have? You have a toolbox that contains multiple models. You are writing a Python script that will import this toolbox using `arcpy.ImportToolbox()` and then run the models as necessary. What do you want to do now?

Comment: I want to share this toolbox between collegaues and because of different locations `arcpy.ImportToolbox()` which was made on my computer will not run on the other one because of another location. I.e. I have `arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"D:\Data\Folder\toolbox.tbx")` and other user placed in E:\Data\NewFolder\toolbox.tbx. In this case script will give an error. So is that possible to calculate the path to the only script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your script is imported into the toolbox, this will provide the path to the toolbox

```
pathname = os.path.realpath(__file__)
pathname = pathname.split(".tbx",1)[0]+".tbx"
```

Comment: If you're operating on paths, just use `os.path.basename()`. This will work properly if the path contains `.tbx`.

Comment: @Paul I tried both methods you recommended, I had imported script but it gave me a path like `C:\Windows\system32\script` while toolbox is located in for example D:\Data\Folder\

Comment: @TunaSammich, I got the result like in my comment below

Comment: @PavelPereverzev, it's possible you'll need to grab `__file__` before you import the toolbox.